# Moveable controls not scrolling with the content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, moveable

I am using [Moveable](https://github.com/daybrush/moveable) library to drag and resize elements.

Below is my code for the vuejs app.

```
      moveable: {
        draggable: true,
        throttleDrag: 0,
        resizable: true,
        throttleResize: 1,
        keepRatio: false,
        scalable: true,
        throttleScale: 0,
        rotatable: true,
        throttleRotate: 0,
        pinchable: true, // ["draggable", "resizable", "scalable", "rotatable"]
        origin: false
      }
```

Below is the HTML code for the same

```
        <div id="editor">
          <Moveable
           class="moveable"
           v-bind="moveable"
           @drag="handleDrag"
           @resize="handleResize"
           @scale="handleScale"
           @rotate="handleRotate"
           @warp="handleWarp"
           @pinch="handlePinch"
         >
          <span>
           This is moveable div
          </span>
         </Moveable>
       </div>
```

So it appears like below.

[image]

But when I drag the moveable element, controls are not getting dragged along with with the element. It is getting fixed.

[image]

I also tried to give the container property to the moveable object like this
`container: document.getElementById('editor')`, but then also it's not working as expected.

I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a fix or workaround?